# Sync data between SQL Server on localhost and cloud-based SQL Server automatically

Tags: sql-server, azure, cloud, database-backups

I have already searched many times but did not find a suitable solution. I am developing a WPF application. I am using SQL Server as database on my local machine.

I have a cloud SQL Server database (AWS or Microsoft Azure etc).

Now the thing I want to achieve is that I want my local machine's database to keep syncing (backing up) data with the cloud database automatically so that I do not have to worry about data loss if something happened to my local machine, since I will always have a copy of database in the cloud.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Does it need to be two way sync?

Comment: yes it is two way sync localhost to cloud and cloud to localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try Replication and MS Sync framework.

Replication:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx

Sync Framework:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2190.tutorial-synchronizing-sql-server-and-sql-server-compact-sync-framework.aspx

Comment: You'll want to add some retry logic to handle those cases where the service is interrupted using the sync framework.